# Remove null list-columns

Tags: r, purrr

I have a data frame with null list columns, similar to this:

```
null_list <- list(NULL, NULL, NULL) %>% enframe()
null_list
#   name value 
#  <int> <list>
#1     1 <NULL>
#2     2 <NULL>
#3     3 <NULL>
```

I'd like to remove all columns that only contain NULL values like the "value" column above, because when I try to unnest_wider these columns (as part of a loop), I receive the error "replacement has length zero."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `select_if`.  `NULL` doesn't exist within a `vector`.  So, the condition should be to check if the column is a `list` and if `all` the elements are `NULL` (`is.null`), negate (`!`) to `select` all the other columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
null_list %>% 
    select_if(~ !(is.list(.) && all(map_lgl(., is.null))))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#   name
#  <int>
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
```

NOTE: This check if all the values in the `list` are `NULL` and then it removes those columns

---

If it is deeply nested,

```
example %>%     
    select(where(~ !(is.list(.) && is.null(unlist(.)))))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      a     b c         
#  <dbl> <dbl> <list>    
#1     1     4 <NULL>    
#2     2     5 <NULL>    
#3     3     6 <list [3]>
```

Or to select only the `list` column with any non-NULL elements

```
example %>%     
    select(where(~ is.list(.) && !is.null(unlist(.))))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#   c         
#  <list>    
#1 <NULL>    
#2 <NULL>    
#3 <list [3]>
```

#### data

```
 example <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6),
   c = list(NULL, NULL, list(1,2,3)),
   d = list(NULL, NULL, list(x = NULL, y = NULL, z = NULL)))
```

Comment: or @Onyambu, what about a situation where a list column has a deeper nested list that contains all NULLs?   `example <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6), c = list(NULL, NULL, list(x = NULL, y = NULL, z = NULL)))`

Comment: Thank you very much. This may be bordering on a new question, but in this case I'm looking to select only list columns, but ones that don't have all nulls in a deeper layer. So in this updated example, I'd be looking to just select column c: `example <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6), c = list(NULL, NULL, list(1,2,3)), d = list(NULL, NULL, list(x = NULL, y = NULL, z = NULL)))`

Comment: No, what you have there currently is perfect. You saved me hours, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Base R, you could do:

```
null_list[colSums(sapply(null_list,lengths))>0]
# A tibble: 3 x 1
   name
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

You could also use `select_if` from tidyverse

```
 library(tidyverse)
 null_list %>%
    select_if(map_lgl(.,~sum(lengths(.x))>0))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
   name
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
library(tibble)

null_list <- list(NULL, NULL, NULL) %>% enframe()

> null_list
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   name value 
  <int> <list>
1     1 <NULL>
2     2 <NULL>
3     3 <NULL>


null_list <- rbind(null_list, c(3, "a"))

> null_list
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  name  value    
  <chr> <list>   
1 1     <NULL>   
2 2     <NULL>   
3 3     <NULL>   
4 3     <chr [1]>

null_list <- null_list[!unlist(lapply(null_list$value, is.null)),]

null_list

> null_list
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  name  value    
  <chr> <list>   
1 3     <chr [1]>
```